Export CSV Time Series by Land Cover GEE
so here is my full code, or you can access the link : https://code.earthengine.google.com/2f7b41657b6c4ed89053535bacbb07cb
I'm trying to make a timeseries vegetation index (ndvi,ndmi,etc) by a land cover for 2023-2024 with a 10 % of. cloud cover. But, the problem is user memory limit exceedeed. And I think we can try another approached with export the table data into .csv. file.
var image = L8.filterBounds(roi)
            .filterDate('2023-01-01','2024-04-30')
            .filterMetadata('CLOUD_COVER','less_than',10)
            .mean()
            .clip(roi)
            
Map.addLayer(image, {bands:['B4','B3','B2']},'TrueColor')

//Merge into one FeatureCollection and print details to consloe
var classNames = tWater.merge(tBuilt).merge(tPerkebunan).merge(tSawah).merge(tForest);
print(classNames);

//Extract training data from select bands of the image, print to console
var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B5', 'B6', 'B7'];
var training = image.select(bands).sampleRegions({
  collection: classNames,
  properties: ['landcover'],
  scale: 30
});
print(training);


//Train classifier - e.g. cart, randomForest, svm
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileCart().train({
  features: training,
  classProperty: 'landcover',
  inputProperties: bands
});

//Run the classification
var classified = image.select(bands).classify(classifier);

//Centre the map on your training data coverage
Map.centerObject(classNames, 11);
//Add the classification to the map view, specify colours for classes
Map.addLayer(classified,
{min: 0, max: 4, palette: ['blue', 'red', 'green','yellow']},
'classification');

//Merge into one FeatureCollection
var valNames = vWater.merge(vBuilt).merge(vPerkebunan).merge(vSawah).merge(vForest);

var validation = classified.sampleRegions({
  collection: valNames,
  properties: ['landcover'],
  scale: 30,
});
print(validation);

//Compare the landcover of your validation data against the classification result
var testAccuracy = validation.errorMatrix('landcover', 'classification');
//Print the error matrix to the console
print('Validation error matrix: ', testAccuracy);
//Print the overall accuracy to the console
print('Validation overall accuracy: ', testAccuracy.accuracy());

Export.image.toDrive({
  image:classified,
  description:'Cisangkuy',
  scale:30,
  region:roi
})


// raster to vector conversion 
var water = classified.eq(0)
var built = classified.eq(1)
var perkebunan = classified.eq(2)
var sawah = classified.eq(3)
var hutan = classified.eq(4)

var class_water = classified.updateMask(water).reduceToVectors({geometry: roi, scale:30})
var class_built = classified.updateMask(built).reduceToVectors({geometry: roi, scale:30})
var class_perkebunan = classified.updateMask(perkebunan).reduceToVectors({geometry: roi, scale:30})
var class_sawah = classified.updateMask(sawah).reduceToVectors({geometry: roi, scale:30})
var class_hutan = classified.updateMask(hutan).reduceToVectors({geometry: roi, scale:30})

Map.addLayer(class_water , {} , 'water_vector' )

print( 'class_water', class_water)

var water_list = class_water.toList(class_water.size())

var geomwater = water_list.map(function(ele){
  return ee.Feature(ele).geometry()
})

class_water = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon(geomwater))




var built_list = class_built.toList(class_built.size())

var geombuilt = built_list.map(function(ele){
  return ee.Feature(ele).geometry()
})

class_built = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon(geombuilt))



var perkebunan_list = class_perkebunan.toList(class_perkebunan.size())

var geomperkebunan = perkebunan_list.map(function(ele){
  return ee.Feature(ele).geometry()
})

class_perkebunan = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon(geomperkebunan))



var sawah_list = class_sawah.toList(class_sawah.size())

var geomsawah = sawah_list.map(function(ele){
  return ee.Feature(ele).geometry()
})

class_sawah = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon(geomsawah))


var hutan_list = class_hutan.toList(class_hutan.size())

var geomhutan = hutan_list.map(function(ele){
  return ee.Feature(ele).geometry()
})

class_hutan = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.Geometry.MultiPolygon(geomhutan))




var regions = ee.FeatureCollection([class_water , class_built , class_perkebunan , class_sawah, class_hutan]).flatten()

print('regions', regions)

var l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC09/C02/T1_TOA")
        .filterBounds(roi)
        .filterDate('2023-01-01','2024-04-30')
        
var addNDVI = function(image){
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5','B4']).rename('ndvi')
  
  return image.addBands(ndvi)
}

var addNDMI = function(image){
  var ndmi = image.normalizedDifference(['B5','B6']).rename('ndmi')
  
  return image.addBands(ndmi)
}

var l8 = l8.map(addNDVI)
var l8 = l8.map(addNDMI)

print(l8)

var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection:l8.select('ndvi') , 
  regions: regions , 
  reducer:ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  band: 'ndvi', 
  scale:30}).setChartType('LineChart')
  .setSeriesNames(['class_water' ,  'class_built' , 'class_perkebunan' ,  'class_sawah', 'class_hutan'])
  .setOptions({
    interpolateNulls: true,
    lineWidth: 1 ,
    pointSize: 3 ,
    title:'NDVI chart for all LULC classes',
    hAxis:{title:'Date'},
    vAxis:{title:'NDVI'}
  })
  
print(chart)

Here it is, what I've tried before. However, the results only contain one time series data. Meanwhile, there are 5 types of data classes that we want to display.
var clippedS2_ndvi = l8.select(['ndvi']);

// Collect image date and ndvi mean value for all features
var dat = clippedS2_ndvi.map(function(image) {
  return image.reduceRegions({
     collection:roi ,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean().setOutputs(['ndvi']), 
    scale: 10
  }).filter(ee.Filter.neq('ndvi', null))
    .map(function(f) { 
      return f.set('date', image.date().format('YYYY-MM-dd'));
    });
}).flatten();

var format = function(table, rowId, colId) {
  var rows = table.distinct(rowId);
  var joined = ee.Join.saveAll('matches').apply({
    primary: rows,
    secondary: table,
    condition: ee.Filter.equals({
      leftField: rowId,
      rightField: rowId
    })
  });
  return joined.map(function(row) {
    var values = ee.List(row.get('matches'))
      .map(function(feature) {
        feature = ee.Feature(feature);
        var ndvi_val = ee.List([feature.get('ndvi'), -9999]).reduce(ee.Reducer.firstNonNull());
        return [feature.get(colId), ee.Number(ndvi_val).format("%.3f")];
      });
    return row.select([rowId]).set(ee.Dictionary(values.flatten()));
  });
};

// Apply format function to the dat object
var sentinelNDVI_Results = format(dat, 'ID', 'date');

// Export data frame to Google Drive as a CSV
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: sentinelNDVI_Results,
  description: 'landsat_NDVI_TS',
  folder: 'earthengine',
  fileNamePrefix: 'landsat_ndvi_ts_demo_',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});

